# SignalR 1.x self-hosting in .net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, signalr

I have a need for running a windows service that hosts a signalr hub.  We would prefer the installation size to be minimal and as a result we would prefer to target .net 4 since our clients typically run on Windows 7

I've been trying to get self hosting setup in a console application using signalr 1.2.2 and I am having the hardest time since it wants to reference the 4.5 only versions of OWIN.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to host a signalR 1.X application in .Net 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can only have web hosting (IIS) for signalR 1.X projects